# Why does a UICollectionViewCell with a UIButton have a monochrome/tinted image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage, ios7

I create a UICollectionView and add a single cell who's only subview is a UIButton.  That button has its title and image set.  I've verified that the image data is correct in the debugger.

When the button is drawn on screen I see the text and the image however the image looks as if it has been filled with the tint color, obscuring all of the image other than its shape.

What am I missing here to have this show up as a normal button should?

## Update

It turns out this is not specific to UICollectionView but rather all UIButtons in iOS7.

iOS 7 makes all images in buttons behave as template images using the alpha channel of the image in concert with the tint color to produce the image (much like the images in a tab bar).  There's a new renderingMode property on UIImage which is defaulted to "automatic" which lets the context decide (which is template style for buttons)

This can be circumvented using the new [imageWithRenderingMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/imageWithRenderingMode%3a): method on UIImage:

```
UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Foo.png"];
myImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[button setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to avoid this is to use a different `UIButtonType`. It's `UIButtonTypeSystem` on IOS 7 that has this behaviour, so you could use a custom button instead:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the UIButton's background color lightText in this way, it will not close the button image.

```
UIButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightText
```